# Can't get cookies from browser on front-end side

Tags: javascript, cookies

I finished server side of cookies authorization where I in responses set cookies and i also get cookies. So now I need to check if there is `Access token`, but a can't get it.

This is my redux thunk where auto login if `Access token` didn't expired:

```
export const getMe = createAsyncThunk(
    'auth/getMe',
    async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/users/user`)

            console.log(document.cookie)

            return data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
)
```

In line where i log in console `document.cookie` i just get empty strings, however `Access token` is set in cookies.

This is how I set cookies:

```
const accessDateExpiration = createDateForCookie(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)

res.cookie('AccessToken', `${sessionAfterRefreshing.AccessToken}`, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    expires: accessDateExpiration
})
```

I tried using packages as `js-cookie` and `browser-cookies`, but they didn't worked out as well.

Maybe there is problem in cookie settings I set:  `hhtpOnly: true`, `secure: true`.

Comment: Not "maybe", but definitively. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#httponly: _"[httpOnly] Forbids JavaScript from accessing the cookie, for example, through the Document.cookie property. Note that a cookie that has been created with HttpOnly will still be sent with JavaScript-initiated requests, for example, when calling XMLHttpRequest.send() or fetch(). This mitigates attacks against cross-site scripting (XSS)."_

Answer (score 2):

When i was writing question i got an idea and after tried that it worked.
So the problem was in httpOnly option. I set it to false and all started working